# Xcode 14.3 Rosetta build with command line

Tags: swift, xcode, fastlane, rosetta, rosetta-2

As Apple removed x86_64 support for Xcode and introduced sperate simulators for Rosetta, I wondered how I could run my app on a Rosetta simulator via cli.

This is also needed for fastlane. (see [Fastlane Issue](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/21194))

In the release notes of Xcode 14.3 nothing regarding the cli is mentioned. ([Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-14_3-release-notes))

Comment: https://sarunw.com/posts/open-using-rosetta-in-xcode-14-3/

Comment: @Cyberbeni This is not CLI releated, this is just for Xcode UI. I need the CLI Parameter/Command for that.

Comment: Did you find any hint about it?

Comment: @Onur nope nothing, the only thing which I could imagine, is that Apple detects in the background if Rosetta is necessary and activates it on its own - but that's just a guess

Comment: @kaulex unfortunately they do not do this :(

Comment: this is a huge issue for us now, seems like apple trying to kill all hacks of rosetta for good. and we are squeezed in the middle between them and the lazy enterprise that provides us with sdks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Github Issue](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/21194#issuecomment-1551152382) which I opened for fastlane as well a user pointed out that following command can be used to build for Rosetta Simulator.

```bash
xcodebuild -workspace App.xcworkspace -scheme App -destination "platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 13,arch=x86_64" build
```

**Fastlane**

There is a new `run_rosetta_simulator` option on scan now.

Comment: did you ever get that option to run? If I run `fastlane action scan` to see all available options I see the parameter but when I try to run the action with it, fastlane says "Could not find option 'run_rosetta_simulator' in the list of available options".

Comment: never mind, I think it was a versioning problem. Provided version >= 2.213.0

Answer (score -1):

for Xcode 14.3 + please follow this to Open using Rosetta in Xcode 14.3+

To run an app on a Rosetta simulator, you need to do the followings.

1. Go to the "Product" menu in the menu bar and select Destination > Destination Architectures > Show Rosetta Destinations.
   You will see architecture in parenthesis next to the simulator. In this case, it is Rosetta.
2. You will see a Rosetta architecture in parenthesis next to simulator names.

If you want to run on both architectures, select the "Show Both" option.

- Go to the "Product" menu in the menu bar and select Destination > Destination Architectures > Show Both.

Reference: https://sarunw.com/posts/open-using-rosetta-in-xcode-14-3/